# Accessing Class Member in different CUDA kernels

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a GPU-only class `T` which I want to create on GPU but have a reference to which on the CPU, so I can send the link as an argument to different CUDA kernels.

```
class T
{
public:
    int v;
public:
    __device__ T() { v = 10; }
    __device__ ~T() {}
    __device__ int compute() { return v; }
};
```

Here are the kernels that I was to create the class instance and to call the `compute()` function.

```
__global__ void kernel(T* obj, int* out)
{
    if(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x == 0) {
        out[0] = obj->compute(); // no kernel error, but it returns garbage
    }
}

__global__ void cudaAllocateGPUObj(T* obj)
{
    if(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x == 0) {
        obj = new T;
        // if I call `out[0] = obj->compute();` here, everything works fine
    }
}
```

The main function simply allocates memory for the pointer of type `T*` which later is used as an argument for the `cudaAllocateGPUObj`.

```
int main()
{
    int cpu, *gpu;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu, sizeof(int));
    T* obj;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&obj, sizeof(T*));
    cudaAllocateGPUObj<<<1,1>>>(obj);
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(obj, gpu);
    cudaMemcpy(&cpu, gpu, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("cudaMemcpy\nresult: %d\n", cpu);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this code (as specified in the comments in the code) is that when I call `out[0] = obj->compute();` in the `cudaAllocateGPUObj` kernel and transfer the obtained value to the CPU, everything is correct. But if I want to obtain the member value in another kernel, it becomes garbage, though if I change the return value from the `v` variable to a constant, everything works fine.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a parameter to a CUDA kernel, it is a pass-by-value mechanism.  You have started with a pointer to an object:

```
T* obj;
```

then, instead of allocating storage for the object, you allocate storage for another pointer:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&obj, sizeof(T*));
```

so we're headed down the wrong path here.  (This is a logical C programming error at this point.)   Next, in the allocate kernel, the `obj` parameter (which now points to some location in GPU memory space) is passed **by value**:

```
__global__ void cudaAllocateGPUObj(T* obj)
                                      ^^^ pass-by-value: local copy is made
```

Now, when you do this:

```
        obj = new T;
```

You create a **new pointer**, and overwrite the local copy of `obj` with that new pointer.  So of course that works locally, but the copy of `obj` in the calling environment is not updated with that new pointer.

One possible method to fix this is to create a proper pointer-to-pointer methodology:

```
$ cat t5.cu
#include <stdio.h>

class T
{
public:
    int v;
public:
    __device__ T() { v = 10; }
    __device__ ~T() {}
    __device__ int compute() { return v; }
};

__global__ void kernel(T** obj, int* out)
{
    if(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x == 0) {
        out[0] = (*obj)->compute(); 
    }
}

__global__ void cudaAllocateGPUObj(T** obj)
{
    if(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x == 0) {
        *obj = new T;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int cpu, *gpu;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu, sizeof(int));
    T** obj;
    cudaMalloc(&obj, sizeof(T*));
    cudaAllocateGPUObj<<<1,1>>>(obj);
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(obj, gpu);
    cudaMemcpy(&cpu, gpu, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("cudaMemcpy\nresult: %d\n", cpu);
    return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t5 t5.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t5
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
cudaMemcpy
result: 10
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```